# $f(x+y) +y$ does not exceed $f(f(f(x)))$

Tags: functions, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

Find all real to real functions for which $f(x+y) +y$ does not exceed $f(f(f(x)))$ for all real $x,y$

I don't feel like substituting values is that useful, except probably substituting $x=0$, which gives a really nice bound on $f(y)$, but other than that, I can't quite find anything else useful, at least not in my opinion.

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Comment: @JackM I was doing problems from B.J Venkachatala's Functional Equations : a problem solving approach when I modified one of the questions to get this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choosing $y:=f(f(x))-x$,we imply :
$$f(f(x))\le x$$
Thus $$f(x+y)+y \le f(x)$$
Thus $$f(x+y)+y \le f( (x+y)-y) \le f(x+y)+y$$
Hence, $$f(x+y)+y=f(x)$$
Hence forth the conclusion.
**Comment**
It seems to me that if we impose that $y$ must be nonnegative in the very first hypothesis, we will have non linear solutions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this answers the question? it seems to be obvious but i don’t to get it. Is there only one class of functions satisfying the condition $f(x+y)+y = f(x)$?

Comment: @rarwoan Dear rarwoan, I'm not sure which part you think I should be more clear, would you mind telling me? I'm always welcome any comment on my post.

Comment: Concerning your last question. So you see, we have: $$ f(x+y) +x+y = f(x)+x$$ for all $x,y$, thereforce the function $g(x)= f(x)+x$ must be a constant function. Hence there is a constant $c$ such that $$g(x)=c$$ that means $$f(x)=c-x$$ .So you have a class of solution to this problem, depending on what $c$ you want.

Comment: Why if $f(f(x)) \le x \Rightarrow f(f(f(x)))\le f(x)$ ?

Comment: @Cesareo: Dear Cesaro, you can replace $x:=f(x)$ in the first inequality.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Yes! So simple as that. Thanks.